# PHP Posting Images to Twitter with Link to Webpage?

Tags: php, api, url, twitter

I'm having a hard time using the "link shortening" service in the twitter API

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tco-link-wrapper/faq

I'm under the impression that a standard type of link should automatically become shortened and clickable when it passes through the API. Yet regardless of how I send the link through, its always as non-clickable text...never shortened, and always counting against the 140 limit.

When using the 1.1 api, how do we direct twitter to deal with URLs?

```
//this here is simply binary stuff uploaded and posted, using twitteroath library
$media = ss_get_image_binary($file_attachment_path);            

$params = array(
    'media[]' => "{$media};type=image/jpeg;filename={$file_attachment_path}",           

);      

$resource_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json';
```

the link part:

```
//I'm making my own hashtags, and counting post length stuff myself...
//the backlink variable here is just a typical http: link
$hashtags = ss_make_hastags($tags, $id);    

$title = ss_twitter_status_format($image->post_title, $hashtags);

$backlink = get_permalink($id);

$params['status'] = $backlink . ' ' . $hashtags;
```

//lastly, everything is posted to twitter

```
$connection = ss_twitter_communication_setup(); 

$tweet = $connection->post($resource_url, $params);
```

The image and status are posting fine. The links never become "active" or clickable. And they count against the 140 limit.

one more thing --

This is the class that everything leads back to, setting up communication

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
```

Comment: Try posting your code.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem:

LOCALHOST does not work.

*facepalm*

Comment: still helpful in 2019!